# How to Convert Text String to Number within the importhtml function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, html-parsing

I'm unable to Sort Column Z because my Importhtml formula is returning a text string. How do I convert the text string to a number so I can sort the Column. [Screenshot of Formula and Result on Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPi5U.png)

Here is the Google Sheets formula that parses a text/numbered string as a text string (On Column Z3 I get 386.02B):

How do I convert it to a number so I am able to sort properly?

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$D3,"table",9),4,2),"*",""),)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the Z column to numbers, simply use a helper column like this:

Insert this formula in AA3 `=ArrayFormula(IF(Z2:Z="",,REGEXREPLACE(Z2:Z,"[a-zA-Z]", "")*1))`.

Breakdown:
1 - `REGEXREPLACE(Z2:Z,"[a-zA-Z]", "")` Replace all letters.
2 - `*1` make sure the the result is converted to a number.
3 - `ArrayFormula(IF(Z2:Z="",,` to enable array formula without the need to drag down the cell.

I hope this answers your question.